# Feed stops getting updates earlier than month ago

Tags: bug, ios-app, feed

Swipe in the feed page stops updating for oldest posts:

> [image: feed]

- App Version: 1.6.4
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2.1 (Build 14D27)

Comment: Well I don't think the feed actually needs to go back that far. The loading indicator should probably not be there if there's nothing more to load though.

Comment: @Cai I agree. Such indicator is confusing me. Looks like very slow connection or another networking problem.